# Using Regex to replace a word (place holder) in a .docx document with multi-line text. What is the newline code to use?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

Microsoft suggests using Regex to replace text in Word documents, like this:

```
// To search and replace content in a document part.
public static void SearchAndReplace(string document)
{
    using (WordprocessingDocument wordDoc = WordprocessingDocument.Open(document, true))
    {
        string docText = null;
        using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(wordDoc.MainDocumentPart.GetStream()))
        {
            docText = sr.ReadToEnd();
        }

        Regex regexText = new Regex("Hello world!");
        docText = regexText.Replace(docText, "Hi Everyone!");

        using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(wordDoc.MainDocumentPart.GetStream(FileMode.Create)))
        {
            sw.Write(docText);
        }
    }
}
```

This works very well with .docx documents except when you try to replace the text with a multi-line replacement, i.e. let's say you want "Hello World!" to become (two lines):

Hello
World!

Using something like "docText = regexText.Replace(docText, "Hello\r\nWorld!");" doesn't seem to work. In that case, the "\r\n" seems to be ignored and you get "HelloWorld!" in the .docx document.

So, what is the proper line separation code to use with regex for .docx documents? Thanks.

Comment: I think `wordDoc.MainDocumentPart.GetStream()` doesn't return the plain text, but the xml structure, where newlines are encoded with `<w:br/>`. I suggest to set a breakpoint in your program to check the content of `docText`. Maybe using https://github.com/xceedsoftware/docx is simpler here.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. It is indeed xml and it looks like there's no easy way to put text on a new line via regex.

Comment: Have you already tried using `\n` instead of `\r\n`?

Comment: Yes. It doesn't work. As cad pointed out above, a .docx document is xml and a single line of text in the document is actually a fairly complex xml construct.